# Storybook build failed with TS error ' Interface 'Event' incorrectly extends interface 'KeyboardEvent'' in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, storybook, angular-storybook

I have Storybook installed in my angular project and everything worked fine until today, when I have run `yarn install` and after this storybook build fails with following TS error

> node_modules/@storybook/api/dist/ts3.9/modules/shortcuts.d.ts:55:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'Event' incorrectly extends interface 'KeyboardEvent'.
> ERR!   Types of property 'target' are incompatible.
> ERR!     Property 'prototype' is missing in type '{ tagName: string; addEventListener(): void; removeEventListener(): boolean; dispatchEvent(event: Event): boolean; getAttribute(attr: string): string | null; }' but required in type 'EventTarget'.
> ERR!
> ERR! 55 export interface Event extends KeyboardEvent {
> ERR!                     ~~~~~
> ERR!
> ERR!   node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5144:5
> ERR!     5144     prototype: EventTarget;
> ERR!              ~~~~~~~~~
> ERR!     'prototype' is declared here.
> Blockquote

package.json

```
  "name": "tour",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "docs:json": "compodoc -p ./tsconfig.json -e json -d .",
    "storybook": "npm run docs:json && start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "npm run docs:json && build-storybook"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.19",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/angular": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.2.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "tour": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/tour",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "tour:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "tour:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "tour:build"
          }
        },
        "storybook": {
          "builder": "@storybook/angular:start-storybook",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "tour:build",
            "port": 6006
          }
        },
        "build-storybook": {
          "builder": "@storybook/angular:build-storybook",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "tour:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Has someone encountered this before? Any idea what could I have done wrong here?

Comment: We're seeing the same issue, but with React. No idea what the problem is so far, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my project, the problem was the dependency

> "@types/node": "^18.7.23"

Deleted caret:

> "@types/node": "18.7.23"

The problem has gone away.
(^version “Compatible with version”, will update you to all future minor/patch versions, without incrementing the major version. ^2.3.4 will use releases from 2.3.4 to <3.0.0. --> [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json))

Comment: Hey @Ranieri, thanks for a solution and a fast answer, it works perfectly well